# i want to delete spesific word in string vector. why doesnt this work?

Tags: c++

so the task is to make two functions 1)print function and 2)"word" removal function in string vector if it exists,so problem is it doesn' t delete "war" from vector;

i want to delete "war" from vector.why this code doesnt work?

```
    void printVec(vector<string> x) {
       for (int i{};i < x.size();i++) {
           cout << x[i] << "\t";
       }
       cout << endl;
   }
   void erazeVec(vector<string> vec) {
       for (size_t i{0};i < vec.size();) {
           if (vec[i] == "war") {
               vec.erase(vec.begin() + i);
           }
           else {
               i++;
           }
       }
   }
   int main() {
       vector<string> vec;
       string word;
       while (cin >> word) {
           vec.push_back(word);
       }
       printVec(vec);
       erazeVec(vec);
       printVec(vec);
   }
```

Comment: To change any parameters you'll need to pass them by reference.

Comment: `void erazeVec(vector<string> vec)` -> `void erazeVec(vector<string>& vec)`

Comment: *i want to delete "war" from vector* --  `#include <algorithm> ... vec.erase(std::remove(vec.begin(), vec.end(), "war"), vec.end());`

Comment: You remove the element from a copy of the vector created in the `main` function, but you print a different copy of the one in the main function. During the function calls the vector in the main function is never modified.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (cin >> word)
```

First this will make your code run for infinite it doesn't give chance to other function to invoke so you should use condition to stop

second `vector<string> &vec` you should pass the vector by reference to reflect all changes happens in the vector to able to delete

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


void printVec(vector<string> &vec) {
       for (int i{};i < vec.size();i++) {
           cout << vec[i] << "\t";
       }
       cout << endl;
   }
   void erazeVec(vector<string> &vec) {
       for (size_t i{0};i < vec.size();) {
           if (vec[i] == "war") {
               vec.erase(vec.begin() + i);
           }
           else {
               i++;
           }
       }
   }
int main() {

       vector<string> vec;
       string word;
       int limit=0;
       while (cin >> word) {
           vec.push_back(word);
           limit++;
           if(limit==1){
           break;
           }
       }
       
       printVec(vec);
       erazeVec(vec);

       cout << "deleted";
       printVec(vec);
   }
```

Comment: or if you want to search in the whole vector until find "war" this's different thing first you should insert the value then call `erazevec()` when the function finds the value you want to delete, I don't mind write this piece of code but I guess the idea delivered